# Rails - able to create a user in console but not on my page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am currently just trying to create this system where you can create an account.
I have uploaded a Gist for it here: [My GistHub link](https://gist.github.com/Veske/7533950) or look at the code below

DB Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131106101452) do

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Create an account") %>
<p class="content">
    <p class="text">
        Account creation</br>
        Fill out the forms below    
    </p>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <div class="forms">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name%>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

    <%= f.submit "Register my Account"%>

    </div>
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :password, length: {minimum: 3}
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
      @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[user_params])
      if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success]= "Registration success!"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
      end 
  end

  def show
    if signed_in?
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

The problem is that when I press submit to pass the info to controller and then again to the database, it gives me an error in rails server log: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tOZkHqPqhlJdgqpEZD7q2R1NvsfKAK9Bwum+I+LcJOI=", "user"=>{"email"=>
"test@test.ee", "name"=>"kapu", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Register my
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1 
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction`

When I do the same thing in rails console, it passes every check and goes into my Database.
So what is going wrong with my implementation currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with your use of strong_paramaters...

In your create method should be calling:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success]= "Registration success!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new        
  end 
end
```

Instead you are calling:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[user_params])
  # etc
end
```